# Combining THREE.ShaderLib.phong and subsurface scattering in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have a mesh in which I use a ShaderMaterial and I use THREE.ShaderLib.phong uniforms. I have linked the map, bump & secular maps texture as well and it all works great. Below is my code.

```
defines = {};
defines[ "USE_MAP" ] = "";
defines[ "USE_BUMPMAP" ] = "";
defines["USE_SPECULARMAP"] = "";

    var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(THREE.ShaderLib.phong.uniforms);
    uniforms.map.value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('source/images/texture-pink.jpg');
    uniforms.bumpMap.value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('source/images/texture-pink-bump.jpg');
    uniforms.bumpScale.value = 0.02;
    uniforms.specularMap.value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('source/images/texture-pink-specular.jpg');

    var parameters = {
        fragmentShader:THREE.ShaderChunk["meshphong_frag"],
        vertexShader:THREE.ShaderChunk["meshphong_vert"], 
        defines: defines,
        uniforms: uniforms,
        lights: true,
        fog: false,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        blending: THREE.NormalBlending,
        transparent: (uniforms.opacity.value < 1.0),
        derivatives : true
    };

    material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(parameters);
```

Below is the result I get.

[image]

I have separate subsurface scattering code for the mesh. Below is my code.

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        varying vec3 v_fragmentPos;
        varying vec3 v_normal;

        void main() {

                vec4 mvPositions = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
                v_fragmentPos =  (modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 )).xyz;
                v_normal =  (modelMatrix * vec4( normal, 0.0 )).xyz;
                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPositions;
        }
    </script>

<script id="fragment_shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        varying vec3 v_fragmentPos;
        varying vec3 v_normal;
        uniform vec3 u_lightPos;

        void main() {

                vec3 _LightColor0 = vec3(1.0,0.5,0.5);  
                float _LightIntensity0 = 2.5;
                vec3 translucencyColor = vec3(0.8,0.2,0.2);
                vec3 toLightVector = u_lightPos - v_fragmentPos;
                float lightDistanceSQ = dot(toLightVector, toLightVector);
                vec3 lightDir = normalize(toLightVector);
                float ndotl = max(0.0, dot(v_normal, lightDir));
                float inversendotl = step(0.0, dot(v_normal, -lightDir));
                vec3 lightColor = _LightColor0.rgb * ndotl / lightDistanceSQ * _LightIntensity0; 
                vec3 subsurfacecolor = translucencyColor.rgb * inversendotl / lightDistanceSQ * _LightIntensity0;
                vec3 final = subsurfacecolor + lightColor;
                gl_FragColor=vec4(final,1.0);
        }
    </script>
```

Pretty basic code I found here [Shader - Simple SSS lighting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119553/shader-simple-sss-lighting-issue). And my material code.

```
sssUniforms = {
   u_lightPos: {type: "v3",value: new THREE.Vector3()}
 };

 var sssMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
   uniforms: sssUniforms,
   vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexShader').textContent,
   fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment_shader').textContent,
 });
```

Below is the result I get with subsurface scattering.

[image]

Now, I am trying to combine these two. I tried THREE.UniformsUtils.merge to merge both the uniforms and I am pretty sure the way I combined the vertex and fragment shader codes is wrong. Since its a string I just copy pasted both in script tags and I am not sure whether thats the right way of doing it. So is this possible in the first place? If yes than can somebody guide me on this. I have fair amount of knowledge with javascript and started getting a hang of threeJS but have zero knowledge when it comes to open GL.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Vertex and fragment shader are the way by which you talk to you GPU pipeline and merging the two string won't result anything until you really understand the mechanism behind this.

So [Phong Shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_shading) is way where in you read the specular+diffused+ambient into your fragment shader for the set of vertices on which you want to apply.

[image]
[Source:wiki]

Now Subsurface Scattering is way by which you consider the **light interaction into the material** where as normally you read the **light interaction with material**

[image]

[Source: [Link](https://renderman.pixar.com/view/subsurface-scattering)]

You can read the [Chapter-16 Nvidia](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch16.html) this solve all the math problem for your solution.

I have created your solution for the Subsurface Scattering you can checkout form 
[Git](https://github.com/koolkap/Sample_Shader). This is Depth Map based SSS.

The code is inspire from the [pixelnerve](http://www.pixelnerve.com/webgl/sss/).

In-short what you are trying to merge THREE.Phong and Subsurface Scattering instead you can extend same sample code for you environment writing down you custom fragment shader ( vertex you can take directly this ).

Comment: thank you for the detailed explanation. I had checked the example from pixelnerve erlier and I have using your project to experiment with fragment shaders. I have reached a point where I can add normal textures with subsurface scattering but finding it hard to set the bump and specular map. Are there any links you can suggest for this?

Comment: @AniketBetkikar ahh i see you mean like this http://softimage.wiki.softimage.com/xsidocs/mat_sss_shaders_AddingBumpandDisplacementMaps.htm

cow image with bump map sure this is doable you can explore this or by Sunday try to update the same git link for the shader.